# Reaching multiple proxy endpoints under "one" location in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a couple of endpoints that I want to reach in the same website by a **single** location block only. Specifically, I want the subpath that going to different endpoint in the **same** website be as suffix to the 'proxy_pass' .

Here's the server block from the config file:

```
    server {
        listen       80;

        server_name  server1raneem.com;

       # root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        proxy_pass http://www.techtarget.com/;

        location ~ ^/(solutions|resources)/ {
        proxy_pass http://www.techtarget.com-$1/;

        }

    # proxy_set_header Host $host;

     }
```

❖ Explanation:
The website's '**server_name**' that I want to reach is '**server1raneem.com**'.
Thus, the subpaths (sub web pages inside that website) should be as follows:

1. https://server1raneem.com/solutions/
2. https://server1raneem.com/resources/

I have tried the 'Regular Expression' above in the 'server' block, yet it didn't work.

Thus, how can I change my workaround so that I can attach all the possible sub web pages to the same main IP address as suffixes in one 'location' block.